# Maven not using local repository for install-file command

Tags: maven

I am new to Maven, I have a really weird problem that maven installs a jar file in the directory from which I run the `mvn install:install-file` command,  instead of installing in the local repository.

What could be the reason for this strange behavior, please help!

Comment: what error did you see?

Comment: what is the result of following command: mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository

Comment: Do you have a pom for the jar? What exact command you are executing?

Comment: @realspirituals : I am following a tutorial in a book that instructs us to install a jar file in the local repository using the following command: 'mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.apress.gswmbook -DartifactId=test -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dfile=C:\example\test.jar -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true'

Comment: What was the result of this command?

Comment: @cslysy I executed the command: C:\tmp>mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository. The result was that the initially empty tmp folder now has other folders such as com, junit, org etc. The command line output showed that a number of jars were downloaded and it said BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Comment: The point is that this command print out your "localRepository" path between the lines which can be useful to investigate this issue. Could you please edit your answer and paste command result. For example in my case it was: 
c:\>mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository
[INFO]
C:\cslysy\mvn-repo
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Where in my case "C:\cslysy\mvn-repo" is a path to my local repo

Comment: @cslysy: this was the command result, it did not download any folders this time as they were already present:C:\tmp>mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...

[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1

[INFO] --- maven-help-plugin:2.2:evaluate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] No artifact parameter specified, using 'org.apache.maven:standalone-pom:p
om:1' as project.[INFO]
C:\tmp
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

Comment: :) There must be somewhere path to your local repository and you probably cut it out. Lets try with another command: mvn help:effective-settings. Please execute it and paste content of  <localRepository>?</localRepository> tag

Comment: @cslysy: After i add this line ' <localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>' to my settings.xml in the .m2 folder in my user home directory, the result of the command has changed and it shows the ${user.home}/.m2/repository as the local repository. However I am still wondering why Maven could not consider the folder 'repository' in the .m2 folder in my C:/ or ${user.home} folder as the local repository in the first place.

Comment: Indeed, I have expected some anomaly in localRepository configuration but it looks like it is fine. As Alexandr M mentioned above "Do you have a pom for the jar? What exact command you are executing?"

Comment: @cslysy: after removing the local repository settings mentioned in the previous comment and then executing the mvn help:effective-settings command, this is the what i get in the output:  <localRepository xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0">C:\tmp</localRepository>

Comment: @cslysy: The jar does not have a pom bundled in it, the command I am executing is this one: mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.apress.gswmbook -DartifactId=test -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dfile=C:\example\test.jar -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true, however u may be right in pointing out that I might have accidentally removed the path somewhere

Comment: I have executed your command on one of my jar and it works fine - jar was installed under my 'localRepository' without problems. Really strange issue.

Comment: I know it is a strange issue.. thanks for trying to help me figure it out though.